# Rails error Couldn't find Review with 'id'=25

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a reviews show page that is nested under albums routes. On a reviews show page, the URL was http://localhost:3000/albums/2/reviews/19, I changed 19 to a random number of a review i don't have. That led me to an error "couldn't find Review with 'id'=25". I would like to redirect that user to my not_found page I created, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is my error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#show
Couldn't find Review with 'id'=25
Extracted source (around line #59):
57
58
59
60
61
62


    def set_review
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_current_user
```

Reviews controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :destroy]
    before_action :find_album, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :must_login, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @albums = Album.with_recent_reviews #scope
    end

    def show

        #@reviews = Review.where("album_id = ?", params[:album_id])
    end

    def new
        if params[:album_id] && @album = Album.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
            @review = @album.reviews.build
        else
            redirect_to albums_path
        end
    end

    def create
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        #@review.album = @album
        if @review.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            #@review.album
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @review.update(review_params)
            redirect_to album_path(params[:album_id])
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        if current_user.id == @review.user_id
          @album.reviews.find(params[:id]).destroy
          redirect_to album_path(params[:album_id])
        else
           flash[:error] = "Unable to delete your review. Please try again."
           redirect_to album_reviews_path(@review)
        end
      end

    private

    def set_review
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_current_user
        @user = current_user
    end

    def find_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    end

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:title, :date, :content, :album_id, album_attributes:[:artist, :title, :user_id])
    end

end
```

REviews show.html.erb:

```
<h6><strong>
Showing "<%= @review.title %>" for 
<%= @album.artist %> -
<%= @album.title %>
</strong></h6>
<br>
<% if @album.avatar.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(@album.avatar))%>%" style="width:350px;height:350px;">
<% end %>
<br>
<br>
<%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_album_path(@album), class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
<%= link_to 'Delete Album', album_path(@album), method: :delete, class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
<br><br>
<hr>

    <% unless @review.id.nil? %>
        <small>Date written: <%= @review.date.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></small><br>
        <small>Written by: <%= @review.user.name %></small><br>
        <br>
        <strong>Title: <%= @review.title %></strong><br>
        <%= @review.content %><br>
        <br>
        <% if current_user.id == @review.user_id %>
        <%= link_to "Edit Review", edit_album_review_path(album_id: @album.id, id: @review.id), class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', album_review_path(album_id: @album.id, id: @review.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %><br><br>
        <% end %>
        <br><br>
    <% end %>

<br>
<strong>
<%= link_to "Write a New Review", album_path(@album), class: "waves-effect waves-light btn" %></strong>
<br><br>
```

rake routes:

```
    GET /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)  sessions#omniauth

auth_failure_path   GET /auth/failure(.:format) redirect(301, /)

signup_path GET /signup(.:format)   users#new

POST    /signup(.:format)   users#create

signin_path GET /signin(.:format)   sessions#new

POST    /signin(.:format)   sessions#create

signout_path    GET /signout(.:format)  sessions#destroy

logout_path POST    /logout(.:format)   sessions#destroy

not_found_path  GET /not_found(.:format)    pages#not_found

album_reviews_path  POST    /albums/:album_id/reviews(.:format) reviews#create

new_album_review_path   GET /albums/:album_id/reviews/new(.:format) reviews#new

edit_album_review_path  GET /albums/:album_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format)    reviews#edit

album_review_path   GET /albums/:album_id/reviews/:id(.:format) reviews#show

PATCH   /albums/:album_id/reviews/:id(.:format) reviews#update

PUT /albums/:album_id/reviews/:id(.:format) reviews#update

DELETE  /albums/:album_id/reviews/:id(.:format) reviews#destroy
```

pages controller for not_found path

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :current_user

    def not_found

    end

    private

    def current_user
        super() #looks for same method on what i'm inheriting from (applicationcontroller)
    end

end
```

albums controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_current_user, only: [:new, :index, :new, :edit]
    before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :must_login, only: [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @albums = Album.all.order("artist ASC")

    end

    def show
        @review = @album.reviews.build
        @review.user = current_user
        @reviews = Review.recent #scope shows recent reviews
    end

    def new
        @album = Album.new
        @review = @album.reviews.build
    end

    def create
        @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
        @album.reviews.each { |r| r.user ||= current_user }
        if @album.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update
        @album.user_id = current_user.id
        @album.avatar.purge # or album.avatar.purge_later
        @album.avatar.attach(params[:avatar])
        if @album.update(album_params)
            redirect_to album_path(@album), notice: "Your album has been updated."
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @album.destroy #destroy is for associated objects
        @album.avatar.purge
        redirect_to albums_path
    end

    private

    def set_current_user
        @user = current_user
    end

    def set_album
        @album = Album.exists?(params[:id]) ? Album.find(params[:id]) : nil
        redirect_to not_found_path if @album.nil? 

    end

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:artist, :title, :avatar, :user_id, reviews_attributes:[:title, :date, :content])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rescue block at the top of your ReviewsController like this:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found
```

Then, at the bottom of your file, you can create your `record_not_found` method:

```
private
  def record_not_found
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: true, status: :not_found
  end
```

The `render file:` in this case is going to the `public` directory and displaying the `404.html` view.

Comment: Great! one last question - what if i wanted to change the number 6 in this URL http://localhost:3000/albums/6/reviews/27 to number 7, the album changes but the review stays on the page. how could i fix that?